# VS Code Interactive notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, interactive

i can t use #%% anymore as a jupyternotebook cell. Its not marked as one or visuallized in any way. I tried reinstalling but didn t work.

I recently had a weird message which said something like "save code browsing activated" and casually just clicked away.

Any ideas how to get it back to normal?

I programm with #%% 99% of the time so i am kind of lost right now :D

regards martin

Comment: i just reinstalled the python extension and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are in the right Python virtual environment, inside your VS Code. If you are in a virtual environment where you do not have the ipython packages installed, that would explain it.

Comment: This really isn't an answer. Once you have enough reputation you'll be allowed to write comments but please don't utilize the answer section to write back to OP.

Comment: oh :D thank u any way i just reinstalled the python extension and it worked :)